# Unsure about Keras Functional API for fine-tuning

Tags: keras, deep-learning

i'm learning about Keras and the usage of the functional API, specifically about using the pre-trained VGG16 model for another classification task, and i came across this piece of code:

```
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,  input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
headModel=baseModel.output
headModel=Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel=Dense(D, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel=Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(classes, activation="softmax")(headModel)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
```

The last line, specifically the `baseModel.input` part is what is confusing me. In the [official tutorial](https://keras.io/models/model/) the `inputs` argument receives a tensor that specifies how the input layer should be, and `outputs` the rest of the model:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Dense(32)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```

This model will include all layers required in the computation of b given a.

However in the previous example `baseModel.input` is used for specifying the entirety of the VGG16 model, minus the layer used for the creation of `headModel` (the new section). From the documentation, the `input` property is inherited from the [Layer object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer):

> input
>
> Retrieves the input tensor(s) of a layer.

How is the `Model` class able to build the complete VGG16 model +headModel if i'm only specifying in the constructor the input tensor of the model as `inputs`?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that when instantiating the headless VGG, an Input layer is automatically created and is the return value of `baseModel.input`. Then, it tracks all the computation to the last `headModel`, so there is a graph between `baseModel.input` to `headModel.output`.

Answer (score 0):

`baseModel.input` is the `Input` layer of the VGG network, while `baseModel.output` is the symbolic tensor of the output of the model, so when you build more layers on top of `baseModel.output`, you are implicitly connecting to the same computational graph of the VGG model, so the `Model` class can trace back the output of your last `Dense` layer (the `headModel` variable) to the input of the VGG network.

This is done internally when `keras` tracks the symbolic tensors used to build the model. In the end that is the whole point of the functional API, to easily build models over other pre-built models.